# Multiple radio buttons won't work, just the first one

Tags: html, angular

I'm new at coding and I must be making a simple mistake that I can't figure out.

My angular aplications has two Modals, the first is a form to add and the second is the edit.

When I'm using the first modal the radio button works, but when I try the second the radio buttons wont work. As if they were disabled.

One thing that I've noticed is that when I use the tab button on my keyboard the radio buttons are selectable through the keyboard.

I've also noticed that if I change the code of the modal that has the radio button that was not working before the code that was working this inverts the issue.

The code that is "rendered" first works.

```
<!-- fist RadioButton -->
<div class="md-form">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <p>Tipo da Instituição: </p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input formControlName="tipoedit" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="publica" name="tipoedit"
        value="Publica">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="publica">Publica</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input formControlName="tipoedit" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="privado" name="tipoedit"
        value="Privado">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="publica">Privado</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && fedit.type.errors" class="invalidFeedback">
    <div *ngIf="fedit.type.errors.required">Tipo é obrigatorio</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second RadioButton -->
<div class="md-form">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <p>Tipo da Instituição: </p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input formControlName="tipo" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="publica" name="tipo"
        value="Publica">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="publica">Publica</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input formControlName="tipo" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="privado" name="tipo"
        value="Privado">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="privado">Privado</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && fadd.tipo.errors" class="invalidFeedback">
    <div *ngIf="fadd.tipo.errors.required">Tipo é obrigatorio</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, I'm using java on the back end, but it is not related to the question, so I just edited the question removing the java tag, tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your `for` attributes on the  labels and the fact that you have multiple elements with the same ids. I highly recommend never having two HTML elements with similar ids.

Try changing the ids of your second radio modal (something like `privadoEdit`/`publicaEdit` )and change the `for` attributes accordingly.

*Also, your first modal has `publica` in both your label's `for` attributes, change the second one to `privado`*

Hope this hleps